# Record Access Issue on After Insert Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

A Community User is trying to create a record in a Custom Object, this trigger autofills the account lookup and the account owner is made this custom object owner as well.

Object Level Permission, Account - Public Read Only & Custom Object - Public Read/Write

Without this trigger I am able to create records for that Custom Object but if I try to create a record with this trigger Active - I get an error as

> "Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger AutofillFields caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: AutofillFields: execution of AfterInsert
>   caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only:
>   Trigger.AutofillFields: line 12, column 1"

```
trigger AutofillFields on MyCustomObject__c (After Insert,After Update) {

    List<User> lstUser = [Select Id, ContactID, Contact.AccountID, Contact.Account.OwnerID, Profile.Name FROM User 
                            WHERE Profile.Name LIKE 'Customer Community Name'];

    for(User iusr : lstUser){
        For(MyCustomObject__c irow : Trigger.new){
            IF(UserInfo.getUserId().contains(iusr.ID)){ 
                irow.Account__c = iusr.Contact.AccountID;
                irow.OwnerID = iusr.Contact.Account.OwnerID;                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot have Master Detail Relation between Account and this Custom Object so had to go with Lookup Relationship, Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Why don't you use a before trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Per the SF [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm)

> You can use an object to change its own field values using
>   trigger.new, but only in before triggers. In all after triggers,
>   trigger.new is not saved, so a runtime exception is thrown.

You are attempting to make a change to trigger.new, hence the exception.  You have a few options when you have an error like this

- Use a before trigger, where you can make changes to trigger.new as it
  has not yet been saved.
- If you want to use an after trigger, you must first query the
  records you want to update, and make changes to that    collection
  and use DML to save that collection.